# How to connect to a non-domain network with a domain computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, domain

To connect to my home network (without a domain) from a laptop running Windows XP Pro configured with a domain I removed the domain name configured on the laptop.  I now find that I cannot log in to the laptop at all.  So I cannot even restore the domain name.   Is there some way to get this working again?  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of providing a username (when asked), provide a full username in the format of DOMAIN\USERNAME (you'll need to know the domain).  If this was an Active Directory domain, you may very well be experiencing some permission-related issues.  An administrator on the Active Directory network may have an easier time re-gaining easy control of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide credentials for a local user.

When your laptop was joined to the domain you were logging in through a domain user account. Now that the laptop is not joined to the domain you need to log in through a user that exists on the laptop itself.